# Media Player Controls

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm working on progressbar for length and time of a song in Window Media Player, but I'm stuck at this code. This code is actually for Visual Basic, but I'm using Visual Studio 2015, and "Dim As Integer" statement doesn't work. How can I fix this code to match with my version current.

Thank you so much, guys.

Wesley

Here is code:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       progressBar1.Increment(1);

       Dim Length As Integer = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentMedia.duration
       Dim Current As Integer = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition;

       progressBar1.Value = Current
       progressBar1.Maximum = Length

       if progressBar1.Value = 100 then
           progressBar1.Value = 0
    }

    private void progressBar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Only one (1) of those tags applies.  Pick one and explain better what the problem is (VS2015 includes VB)

Comment: Your code is mixing VB and C#. That won't work.

Comment: And saying *statement doesn't work* doesn't tell us anything at all.

Comment: Don't spam tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C# the code should be:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
     progressBar1.Increment(1);

     //Both currentPosition and duration are doubles
     int length = (int)axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentMedia.duration;
     int current = (int) axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition;

     progressBar1.Value = current;
     progressBar1.Maximum = length;

     if (progressBar1.Value == 100)
          progressBar1.Value = 0
}
```

Take into account that both `currentPosition` and `duration` are doubles, so you will need to cast them or parse them to ints.

Comment: Hi Moondaisy! Thank you for answering me! Everything is good now, but there's a little problem for me, how can I cast them? Could you show me? Sorry I'm so new. :(

Comment: By putting `(int)` like I did in the anwser or `Convert.ToInt32(axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentMedia.duration)`

Comment: Oh my god! Now, It works. Thank you very much, moondaisy. :D